# How to configure application HTTP requests to come from site IP instead of server IP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis

First off I don't usually deal with server configuration and my understanding of it is very basic, so my apologies if this question has already been asked with the correct terminology.

***Scenario:***
I have a server with more than one site hosted on it, for argument's sake the server's IP address is `X`. I've recently deployed a new application to that server and the IP address for that site is `Y`

***Problem:*** The application I've deployed with IP address `Y` is making web requests to an external `API` and that API is restricted to the application with IP address `Y`. However, the requests sent from the application are from IP address `X` of the server.

How can I resolve this?

**Can people please help to appropriately tag this question.**

Comment: Your application needs to bind to the correct IP address when making its outgoing connection.

Comment: Are address X & Y on the same subnet and both assigned to NICs on the webserver?